# Where does entity framework save information about initialized database for current domain?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Entity Framework invokes `Seed` mehtod of `DbContextInitalizer` only first time for application's domain and creates all data about database only one time.

Where does Entity Framework save info about it, so data context creates each time?

Does a way exist to not create the database again for other application, if dbContext uses `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` strategy and other application uses same DataAccess assembly?

Comment: See __MigrationsHistory table.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's so, I forgot about it, EF saves serialized model and creates initial migration. Does model have domain's identifier and if identifier has differences between current identifier, EF will create database again for DropCreateAlways strategy?